# Proving/disproving that a set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble interpretation some equations.

To prove whether a given set is a vector space, I know there are ~10 axioms I need to test, but I'm having trouble interpreting the equations to be able to test the axioms.

Here is one of the equations:

$$V=\big\{x=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3;x_1+x_2+x_3=0 \big\}$$

How do I apply the axioms to this set. Any hints would be great.

EDIT: I think this is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if I'm reading this correctly, so I guess I should be able to just test if this is a subset.
This would mean I need to test:

1. The zero vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is in V
2. V is closed under addition
3. H is closed under multiplication by scalars

Is this the right way to go about this? Would I just plug in for the $x_n$ terms?

Comment: Which axioms are giving you problems?

Comment: @lulu It's not the axioms. I guess I'm just uncertain. Should I just choose two vectors in V and test with those?

Comment: You know it is a subset of a vectorspace and I am quite sure you saw a statement saying when such a subset forms a subspace itself (the statement is the one you wrote in you edit).

Comment: No, it's not enough to just check an example (though working some examples might increase your confidence).  If $\vec x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $\vec y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ are both in $V$ can you show that $\vec x + \vec y \in V$?

Comment: You could show that the map $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ is linear, and that $V$ is the kernel of this map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is indeed correct: Since $V\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and we know $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space, we know that it suffices to check that $V$ is a subspace, i.e.

1. $V$ is nonempty,
2. $V$ is closed under addition, and
3. $V$ has closed under scalar multiplication.

Doug M shows why these hold in his answer. The idea: Pick arbitrary vectors of $V$ and show that they satisfy the three properties. What does an arbitrary vector of $V$ look like?

Answer (score 2):

Closure under addition:

Suppose $\mathbf x,\mathbf y \in V \implies x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$ and $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 0$

$\mathbf x + \mathbf y \implies x_1+y_1 + x_2+y_2 + x_3+y_3 = 0$

Scalar multiplication:

$c\mathbf x = c x_1 + cx_2 + cx_3 = 0$

Now check the remaining.